# Directly render html page on specific element without scroll (Django/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css, django, scroll, anchor

My question is about controlling page scrolling/anchor targets while using Django and Bootstrap.

I have a Django project styled using Bootstrap.

Information is rendered sequentially on a page. New information is added to the bottom of the page each time a user presses a button. This is achieved through loading all the information into a dictionary, but only rendering specific sections of it depending on a variable *count* which stores how far the user is through the case.

When the button is pressed, information is passed to a view which checks its integrity and if acceptable increments a count variable  and redirects the user back to the original page.

The original page now shows new information because of the incremented count variable.

I am trying to use anchors with the URL redirect to ensure the page loads on the new information. These anchors work, but the page is loading from the top each time a user presses the button to advance and then the page scrolls down.

Ideally the page would load directly on the new information or reload where the user clicked submit and then scroll to the new information.

A section of the view to demonstrate the current view handling redirection to the new div.

```
def advance_slide(request, **kwargs):
    ...
    anchor = '#' + 'slide_' + str(slide_id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('case_play', kwargs={'pk': case_id}) + anchor)
```

**Attempts so far**

I optimistically tried changing the scroll-behaviour for the page but this had no benefit.

After this I wondered if the behaviour was a function of Bootstrap and I have searched the Bootstrap documentation for 'anchor' and 'links'. While this got some results I didn't think any of them looked like what I needed.

I have also tried to use JS to render a specific element using the following with the Django template:

```
{% if anchor %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            location.assign('{{anchor}}')
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Here, instead of using the HttpResponseRedirect with an anchor above I simply render the original page again but pass in a variable 'anchor' in context. My hope was before the HTML loads JS would set the window to the required element. Instead, the page loads again at the top and then scrolls down to the desired element (as it did previously). Even if I could change the behaviour to a jump instead of a scroll - I still wouldn't want the page jumping to the top every time the user submits data as some of the scenarios are quite long.

Most posts online feature the opposite problem - people trying to add smooth scroll functionality not remove it.

I could try to rewrite the application so all data progressing is handled with ajax, but this would require doing a lot of data processing in the view I think and means I'd have to write JS rather than Python which I have much less experience with.

I think there are probably several different ways to achieve what I need - loading the html page over a specific html element without any scrolling - but I can't get them working and I'm unclear on what the best solution for this project would be (making as much use of the Django style as possible).

Thanks for your time and any help you can provide.

**Edits**

Following a request for the html. The actual html is very long so I've tried to strip it back to the bare bones. In the html below I've demonstrated what I was trying using the JS approach. The same affect can be achieved in the views without any requirement for this though.

- case_dict is a subset of a dictionary containing all content that I might need to display in the scenario. case_dict contains all the information that needs to be rendered for any given *count* (the variable tracking user progress)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if anchor %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            location.assign('{{ anchor }}')
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}

{% for key, value in case_dict.items %}
    <div id="slide_{{ key }}">
        <p>{{ value.something}}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% if advance == True %}
    <a href="{% url 'advance_slide' pk=case.case_id %}" class="btn btn-success">Next slide</a>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the page loads at the top, then it starts to scroll? Can you post your html too?

Comment: I have posted example html. I haven't posted the actual html as it's hundreds of lines long but hopefully the example above roughly shows the logic. With respect to your first question. When the user clicks the link to advance it sends the data to a url called 'advance_slide' which then redirects to the original 'url' which is renders an updated case_dictionary. When the new information is rendered, regardless of where the user pressed the link the browser jumps back to the top of the web page and then scrolls down to the targeted div.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is the normal behaviour. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/overview/#design-your-urls behaves the same. I suppose the browser doesn't know how long the page will be before loading, so it starts at the top.

Comment: One way to avoid that, is to just do an ajax request to the server which returns the rendered HTML of just the next step. Then you append that HTML after your last step, then scroll.

Comment: I guess the question is if there is any way to overwrite that normal behaviour. Thanks, I thought about using ajax but it will make the logic of the page significantly more complicated. The advance_slide URL updates a database etc. and if I use ajax I will need to be able to send several different types of data from the page to the view and I'm worried I might make a mistake with security (dealing with the csrf tokens etc.). I'll start working on it though in the absence of an alternative.

Comment: Hello, you could hide the whole content via css ans show it back on onload. If the scrolling behavior is set from css, then you can overide it too and set it back on onload.

Comment: Hi G-Cyrillus. Thanks for your comment. I might use this to provide assignments to students. I already tried hiding content using CSS but realised students might be able to inspect the page source and retrieve answers to questions prior to submitting so would like to avoid this if possible.